# Give my azure function access to my Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I want to connect an Azure Function to an Azure SQL Database. For other services, I was used to whitelist my client's Ip address in the database firewall rules. But since Azure Functions have dynamic IP addresses, I am trying to find an alternative solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: SQL DB should have a firewall setting for allowing access to Azure services (such as Azure Functions). Have you enabled that? Does that let your Azure Function connect properly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow Azure resources to access your SQL Server. This will allow Azure platform resources, like functions, access to Azure SQL regardless of what IP they are coming from. However, note that this allows *all* Azure resources to access that SQL Server, *even resources hosted in other subscriptions that you don't own*. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#connections-from-inside-azure.

To set this in the Azure Portal, navigate to your SQL Server instance and go to "Firewalls and virtual networks". From there you have the option to "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server".

[image: Allow Azure services and resources to access this server]

I am not aware of a way to IP-restrict Azure SQL for a specific Azure function other than going with the premium plan.

Answer (score -3):

You need to create a connection string in your application settings.
A function app hosts the execution of your functions in Azure. As a best security practice, store connection strings and other secrets in your function app settings. Using application settings prevents accidental disclosure of the connection string with your code. Please check [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup)

similar [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062933/how-can-i-connect-my-azure-function-with-my-azure-sql)

Comment: This question is unrelated to how to store connection strings.

Comment: Also, you're sharing information that is opinion-based (such as best practices for connection string storage). As for the similar thread, if you feel this question is a duplicate of the question you pointed to, then you should flag the question here as a duplicate.